# Is $\lceil x \rceil=\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm looking for a function that defines $\lceil x \rceil$ and I found the following:

$$\lceil x \rceil=\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))$$

*Explanation:*
first I noticed that plotting $\lceil x \rceil$ yields a graph that looks like a staircase, so I started combining "steps" and offsetting them by $n$
($a$ and $b$ are the upper and lower bounds of the stairs; $a\le 0$)

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=a}^{b}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)+1)$$

but because of the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function, all integers are lowered by $0.5$. So I adjust it with $-\left|\operatorname{sgn}\left(x-n\right)\right|$

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=a}^{b}\left(\operatorname{sgn}\left(x-n\right)-\left|\operatorname{sgn}\left(x-n\right)\right|\right)$$

and finally, I make both functions coincide:

$$\lceil x \rceil=\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))$$

Unfortunately Wolfram Alpha doesn't seem to like this function; I would greatly appreciate it if you could prove this/simplify it  or find a way to rewrite it without the sum

Comment: $|\text{sgn}(x-n)|$ is simply just $1$ so you can simplify your series as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(\text{sgn}(x-n)+\text{sgn}(n))$

Comment: I can't edit my comment but the sum should be $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{x\}}(\text{sgn}(x-n)+\text{sgn}(n))+\text{sgn}(x)$

Comment: Is $sgn(0) = 0$ or is $sgn(0) = 1$?

Comment: Seems to work.  You should trust yourself to verify it.

Comment: It works so long as $x$ is not an integer.  It's off by 1 or 1/2 if $x$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in cases:

1a) $x < 0; x\not \in \mathbb Z$.

Then

$\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))=$

$\frac 12(1 + \sum_{n< x< 0}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)) + \sum_{x< n< 0}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)) + (\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))_{n=0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))=$

$\frac 12(1 + \sum_{n< x< 0}(1-1+1+-1) + \sum_{x< n< 0}(-1-1+1+-1) + (-1-1+1+0)_{n=0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1-1+1+1)=$

$\frac 12(1 + \sum_{n< x< 0}0 + \sum_{x< n< 0}(-2) + (-1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(0)=$

$\sum_{x<n<0} (-1)=\sum_{n=-1;n--}^{\lceil x\rceil}(-1)=-\sum_{n=1}^{|\lceil x\rceil|}1= -|\lceil x\rceil|$ and as $\lceil x\rceil \le 0$ this is equal to $\lceil x\rceil$ (maybe I should note that if $-1 < x < 0$ then $\sum_{n=-1;n--}^{\lceil x\rceil}(-1)$ is $0$ as the condition for the summand is never met so this is a sum with zero terms.)

1b) $x < 0; x\in \mathbb Z$.

This is much as above but we have an addition term $(sgn(x-n)-|sgn(x-n)| +1 sgn(n))_{n=x}= 0-0+1-1= 0$.

Hmmm this *doesn't* seem to work as in this case: $\sum_{x<n<0} (-1)=\sum_{n=-1;n--}^{x+1}(-1)=x+1\ne \lceil x\rceil$

Case 2: $x=0$ then

$\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))=$

$\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{1}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))+(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))_{n=0=x} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))=$

$\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{1}(1-1+1+1)+(0-0+1+0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1-1+1+1)=\frac 12$

Hmm, doesn't seem to work.  If $sgn(0) =1$ (it might, I never know what the conventions is) we still get the error that this is equal to $ 1$.

Case 3:  $x > 0; x\not \in \mathbb Z$.

This is similar to the above.  For $n> x$ we have $(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))= -1-1 + 1 +1 =0$ and for $n<0$ we have $(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))=1-1+1-1=0$ so

$\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))=$

$\frac{1}{2}(1+(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))_{n=0}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))=$

$\frac{1}{2}(1+(1-1+1+0)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}(1-1+1+1)=$

$1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}1 = 1 +\lfloor x \rfloor= \lceil x \rceil$.

And finally.

2b.  $x > 0; x\in \mathbb Z$.

This gives us

$\frac{1}{2}(1+(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))_{n=0}+ \sum_{n=1}^{x-1}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n)))+ (\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-n)|+1+\operatorname{sgn}(n))_{x=0}=$

$\frac 12(1 + 1 + 2(x-1) + (0-0+1+1)= x + \frac 12$.

So

You're formula does work if $x$ is not an integer.